# Rename multiple filename in multiple folders

Tags: bash, shell

I know you can do this to rename all filenames in a single folder with something like this:

```
for file in 1_*; do
    mv "$file" "${file/1_/}"
done
```

However, is there a way to do this across multiple folders? For example, it will search through all the folders in the current directory and change them.

I have `bash` version 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust solution, **assuming you have *GNU* or *BSD*/OSX `find`**:

```
find . -type f -name '1_*' -execdir sh -c 'echo mv -- "$1" "${1#1_}"' _ {} \;
```

<sup>Note:

- This will only *echo* the `mv` commands, to be safe; remove the `echo` to perform actual renaming.

- The OP's substitution, `"${file/1_/}"` was changed to the POSIX-compliant `"${file#1_}"`, which is actually closer to the intent.

- If you truly need a substitution such as `"${file/1_/}"`, which the `sh` on your system *may or may not* support, it is better to explicitly invoke a shell known to support it, such as `bash`.

- Symlinks are *ignored* (both files and directories); use `find -L ...` to include them (both as potential files to be renamed and to make `find` descend into symlinks to *directories*).</sup>

- `find . -type f -name '1_*'` finds all files (`-type f`) with names matching `1_*` (`-name '1_*'`) in the current dir.'s (`.`) subtree.
- `-execdir` executes the command passed to it *in the subdirectory in which the file at hand is located*.
- `sh -c 'echo mv -- "$1" "${1#1_}"' _ {} \;` invokes the default shell (`sh`):

  - with a command string (passed to `-c`)

    - `mv -- "$1" "${1#1_}"` effectively removes prefix `1_` from the filename represented by the first positional parameter (`$1`).
  - and dummy parameter `_` (which `sh` will assign to `$0`, which is not of interest here)
  - and the path of the file at hand, `{}`, which the shell will bind to `$1`;
  - `\;` simply terminates `-execdir`'s argument.

Note that `--` ensures that any filename that happens to start with `-` isn't mistaken for an *option* by `mv` (applies analogously below).

---

`-execdir` is not POSIX-compliant; if a **POSIX-compliant variant** is therefore more cumbersome:

```
find . -type f -name '1_*' -exec sh -c \
  'cd -- "${1%/*}" && f=${1##*/} && echo mv -- "$f" "${f#1_}"' _ {} \;
```

- `cd -- "${1%/*}"` changes to the directory in which the file at hand is located.

  - Note: `cd -- "$(dirname -- "$1")"` is generally more robust, but less efficient; since we know that `$1` is always a *path* rather than a mere filename in this scenario, we can use the more efficient `cd -- "${1%/*}"`.
- `f=${1##*/}` extracts the mere filename from the file path at hand.
- The remainder of the command line then works as above, analogously.

---

**Performance note**:

The above solutions are concise, but *inefficient*, because a shell instance has to be spawned for *each matching file*.

A **potential speed-up** is to use a variant of [peak's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500307/45375), but *only if you avoid calling external utilities* in the `while` loop (except for `mv`):

```
find . -type f -name '1_*' | while IFS= read -r f; do
   new_name=${f##*/}       # extract filename
   new_name=${new_name#1_} # perform substitution
   d=${f%/*}               # extract dir
   echo mv -- "$f" "$d/$new_name"  # call mv to rename
done
```

<sup>The above bears the hypothetical risk of breaking with filenames with *embedded newlines* (very rare); with GNU or BSD `find`, this problem could be solved.</sup>

With this approach, only a *single* shell instance is spawned, which processes all matching filenames in a loop - as long as the *only* external utility that is called in the loop is `mv`, this will generally be faster than the `find`-only solutions with `-exec[dir]`.

Comment: `find . -type f -name '1_*' -execdir sh -c 'echo mv -- "$1" "${1}"' _ {} \;` Your code seems to only work when I try to print out the exact same file name like I do above. If I try to replace it with `"${1/1_}"`, it gives 'bad substitution' error for each file I replace.

Comment: Your version performs no substitution at all (`$1` and `${1}` do the same thing). If expansion (substitution) `"${1/1_}"` fails, you're probably using a (mostly) strictly POSIX-compliant shell such as `dash` on Ubuntu. Can you assume the presence of `bash`? If so, simply replace `sh` with `bash` above, and it should work. Either way, please add your requirements to your _question_.

Comment: @user1798750: On second thought: in your particular case, the alternative substitution `"${file#1_}"` should work (and is actually closer to your intent), which _is_ POSIX-compliant, so it's fine to use `sh` with it; I've added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on too many subtleties, consider this very pedestrian approach, which assumes a bash-like shell and that all the usual suspects (find, sed, ....) are directly available:

```
find . -type f -name "1_*" | while read -r file ; do
   x=$(basename "$file")
   y=$(sed 's/1_//' <<< "$x")
   d=$(dirname "$file")
   mv "$file" "$d/$y"
done
```

(You might want to try this using "mv -i" or "echo mv ....". You might also want to use `find` with the `-follow` option.)

Comment: ++ for an approach that's easier to understand and _potentially_ faster - but only if do _not_ call  _external utilities_ in the loop (except for `mv`). I suggest making the `read` command a little more robust, just to be safe: `IFS= read -r file`.
The `-follow` hint so as to include symlinks is helpful, but please note that `-follow` is deprecated and the `-L` option should be used instead.